# Excel VBA running extremely slow after upgraded to Office365 ProPlus

Tags: excel, vba, office365, slowdown

I paste part of the code as below. This code is to parse a JSON string got from HTTP request, there's no worksheet/workbook operation at all. Before office upgraded to office365 ProPlus, it's quite efficient. But after upgrade, a json which could be parsed less than 2 seconds, costs several minutes. Personally I don't understand the root cause.

Code source: @Tim Hall https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

```
' ============================================= '
' Public Methods
' ============================================= '

''
' Convert JSON string to object (Dictionary/Collection)
'
' @method ParseJson
' @param {String} json_String
' @return {Object} (Dictionary or Collection)
' @throws 10001 - JSON parse error
''
Public Function ParseJson(ByVal json_String As String) As Object
    Dim json_Index As Long
    json_Index = 1

    ' Remove vbCr, vbLf, and vbTab from json_String
    json_String = VBA.Replace(VBA.Replace(VBA.Replace(json_String, VBA.vbCr, ""), VBA.vbLf, ""), VBA.vbTab, "")

    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    Select Case VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
    Case "{"
        Set ParseJson = json_ParseObject(json_String, json_Index)
    Case "["
        Set ParseJson = json_ParseArray(json_String, json_Index)
    Case Else
        ' Error: Invalid JSON string
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '{' or '['")
    End Select
End Function

Private Function json_ParseObject(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Dictionary
    Dim json_Key As String
    Dim json_NextChar As String

    Set json_ParseObject = New Dictionary
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> "{" Then
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '{'")
    Else
        json_Index = json_Index + 1

        Do
            json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "}" Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                Exit Function
            ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "," Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            End If

            json_Key = json_ParseKey(json_String, json_Index)
            json_NextChar = json_Peek(json_String, json_Index)
            Debug.Print "json_Key = " & json_Key & ", json_NextChar = " & json_NextChar
            If json_NextChar = "[" Or json_NextChar = "{" Then
                Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
            Else
                json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End If
End Function

Private Function json_ParseArray(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Collection
    Set json_ParseArray = New Collection

    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> "[" Then
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '['")
    Else
        json_Index = json_Index + 1

        Do
            json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "]" Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                Exit Function
            ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "," Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            End If

            json_ParseArray.add json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
            'DoEvents
        Loop
    End If
End Function

Private Function json_ParseValue(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Variant
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    Select Case VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
    Case "{"
        Set json_ParseValue = json_ParseObject(json_String, json_Index)
    Case "["
        Set json_ParseValue = json_ParseArray(json_String, json_Index)
    Case """", "'"
        json_ParseValue = json_ParseString(json_String, json_Index)
    Case Else
        If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 4) = "true" Then
            json_ParseValue = True
            json_Index = json_Index + 4
        ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 5) = "false" Then
            json_ParseValue = False
            json_Index = json_Index + 5
        ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 4) = "null" Then
            json_ParseValue = Null
            json_Index = json_Index + 4
        ElseIf VBA.InStr("+-0123456789", VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)) Then
            json_ParseValue = json_ParseNumber(json_String, json_Index)
        Else
            Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', null, true, false, '{', or '['")
        End If
    End Select
End Function

Private Function json_ParseString(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As String
    Dim json_Quote As String
    Dim json_Char As String
    Dim json_Code As String
    Dim json_buffer As String
    Dim json_BufferPosition As Long
    Dim json_BufferLength As Long

    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index

    ' Store opening quote to look for matching closing quote
    json_Quote = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
    json_Index = json_Index + 1

    Do While json_Index > 0 And json_Index <= Len(json_String)
        json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)

        Select Case json_Char
        Case "\"
            ' Escaped string, \\, or \/
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
            json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)

            Select Case json_Char
            Case """", "\", "/", "'"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, json_Char, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "b"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, vbBack, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "f"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, vbFormFeed, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "n"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, vbCrLf, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "r"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, vbCr, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "t"
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, vbTab, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Case "u"
                ' Unicode character escape (e.g. \u00a9 = Copyright)
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                json_Code = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 4)
                json_BufferAppend json_buffer, VBA.ChrW(VBA.val("&h" + json_Code)), json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
                json_Index = json_Index + 4
            End Select
        Case json_Quote
            json_ParseString = json_BufferToString(json_buffer, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength)
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Exit Function
        Case Else
            json_BufferAppend json_buffer, json_Char, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
        End Select
    Loop
End Function

Private Function json_ParseNumber(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Variant
    Dim json_Char As String
    Dim json_Value As String

    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index

    Do While json_Index > 0 And json_Index <= Len(json_String)
        json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)

        If VBA.InStr("+-0123456789.eE", json_Char) Then
            ' Unlikely to have massive number, so use simple append rather than buffer here
            json_Value = json_Value & json_Char
            json_Index = json_Index + 1
        Else
            ' Excel only stores 15 significant digits, so any numbers larger than that are truncated
            ' This can lead to issues when BIGINT's are used (e.g. for Ids or Credit Cards), as they will be invalid above 15 digits
            ' See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269370
            '
            ' Fix: Parse -> String, Convert -> String longer than 15 characters containing only numbers and decimal points -> Number
            If Not JsonOptions.UseDoubleForLargeNumbers And Len(json_Value) >= 16 Then
                json_ParseNumber = json_Value
            Else
                ' VBA.Val does not use regional settings, so guard for comma is not needed
                json_ParseNumber = VBA.val(json_Value)
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
End Function

Private Function json_ParseKey(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As String
    ' Parse key with single or double quotes
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = """" Or VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "'" Then
        json_ParseKey = json_ParseString(json_String, json_Index)
    ElseIf JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys Then
        Dim json_Char As String
        Do While json_Index > 0 And json_Index <= Len(json_String)
            json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
            If (json_Char <> " ") And (json_Char <> ":") Then
                json_ParseKey = json_ParseKey & json_Char
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '""' or '''")
    End If

    ' Check for colon and skip if present or throw if not present
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> ":" Then
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting ':'")
    Else
        json_Index = json_Index + 1
    End If
End Function

Private Function json_Encode(ByVal json_Text As Variant) As String
    ' Reference: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt
    ' Escape: ", \, /, backspace, form feed, line feed, carriage return, tab
    Dim json_Index As Long
    Dim json_Char As String
    Dim json_AscCode As Long
    Dim json_buffer As String
    Dim json_BufferPosition As Long
    Dim json_BufferLength As Long

    For json_Index = 1 To VBA.Len(json_Text)
        json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_Text, json_Index, 1)
        json_AscCode = VBA.AscW(json_Char)

        ' When AscW returns a negative number, it returns the twos complement form of that number.
        ' To convert the twos complement notation into normal binary notation, add 0xFFF to the return result.
        ' https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272138
        If json_AscCode < 0 Then
            json_AscCode = json_AscCode + 65536
        End If

        ' From spec, ", \, and control characters must be escaped (solidus is optional)

        Select Case json_AscCode
        Case 34
            ' " -> 34 -> \"
            json_Char = "\"""
        Case 92
            ' \ -> 92 -> \\
            json_Char = "\\"
        Case 47
            ' / -> 47 -> \/ (optional)
            If JsonOptions.EscapeSolidus Then
                json_Char = "\/"
            End If
        Case 8
            ' backspace -> 8 -> \b
            json_Char = "\b"
        Case 12
            ' form feed -> 12 -> \f
            json_Char = "\f"
        Case 10
            ' line feed -> 10 -> \n
            json_Char = "\n"
        Case 13
            ' carriage return -> 13 -> \r
            json_Char = "\r"
        Case 9
            ' tab -> 9 -> \t
            json_Char = "\t"
        Case 0 To 31, 127 To 65535
            ' Non-ascii characters -> convert to 4-digit hex
            json_Char = "\u" & VBA.Right$("0000" & VBA.Hex$(json_AscCode), 4)
        End Select

        json_BufferAppend json_buffer, json_Char, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength
    Next json_Index

    json_Encode = json_BufferToString(json_buffer, json_BufferPosition, json_BufferLength)
End Function

Private Function json_Peek(json_String As String, ByVal json_Index As Long, Optional json_NumberOfCharacters As Long = 1) As String
    ' "Peek" at the next number of characters without incrementing json_Index (ByVal instead of ByRef)
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    json_Peek = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, json_NumberOfCharacters)
End Function

Private Sub json_SkipSpaces(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long)
    ' Increment index to skip over spaces
    Do While json_Index > 0 And json_Index <= VBA.Len(json_String) And VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = " "
        json_Index = json_Index + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function json_StringIsLargeNumber(json_String As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Check if the given string is considered a "large number"
    ' (See json_ParseNumber)

    Dim json_Length As Long
    Dim json_CharIndex As Long
    json_Length = VBA.Len(json_String)

    ' Length with be at least 16 characters and assume will be less than 100 characters
    If json_Length >= 16 And json_Length <= 100 Then
        Dim json_CharCode As String
        Dim json_Index As Long

        json_StringIsLargeNumber = True

        For json_CharIndex = 1 To json_Length
            json_CharCode = VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_CharIndex, 1))
            Select Case json_CharCode
            ' Look for .|0-9|E|e
            Case 46, 48 To 57, 69, 101
                ' Continue through characters
            Case Else
                json_StringIsLargeNumber = False
                Exit Function
            End Select
        Next json_CharIndex
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through it? function by function to check where is it taking time?

Comment: Just anecdotally I have noticed some really stupid and annoying problems with Office 365 ProPlus that do not consistently happen.  Weird things like the formulas bar not updating after selecting different cells, stepping through a macro takes several seconds per line when the whole thing runs in less than a second.  I use Office 2013 at work and my biggest problem is myself, when I close a workbook without saving.  In some ways 365 feels like a step backwards.

Comment: Have you checked the GitHub issues or opened one? https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/issues  Providing info such as alluded to by @SiddharthRout

Comment: Also, rather than just provide code from the source it would be better, IMO, to provide code which would reproduce the problem for those with Office 365 and add info on what you have discovered from trying to identify the delay (then you could add just the bits of source code where you have identified a blockage)

Comment: I am also curious as to did you upgrade Office on an exisiting version or it was a clean install? If it was on an existing version, then completely uninstall Office, using [Easy Fix tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-uninstall-office-dc998d82-350e-432b-a09f-a5225d10b90d) and then re-install 365. Check if you are still facing the problem? I am off to bed but will look at this thread for your response when I wake up...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it was an update upon an existing version. But as all these are controlled by company IT, I can do nothing about your proposal. I've requested IT to downgrade the version to previous one, it's OK now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upgrade of JsonConverter module did help to me. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases/tag/v2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to create a new Excel workbook, then create the worksheets/forms/modules/classes you need and give them the same names. Then copy/paste all VBA code from the original workbook/sheets/forms/modules to the new new ones with ctrl+c/ctrl+v.
If nessesary, also add the needed references to the new workbook.

When you're ready, compile the VBA Project and fix possible remaining errors.
Save and close all workbooks and Excel.
Then open the new workbook again and see if you experience an improvement.

It sure helped me!! (With an automated Excel dashboard wich contains over 10000 lines of VBA code and connects to an SQL Server wich reads and writes over thousands of rows in different databases and displays it in different worksheets with formatting)

With Excel 2013 while updating this workbook it lasted less then 20 seconds. After opening in Excel 365 it took more then 15 minutes. After creating a new workbook and copy paste the contents, it took not more then 20 seconds again.

I hope it can help you too!