# VBA-JSON parser v2.2.3 inconsistent runtime

Tags: json, vba

My work uses an xcel tool that has the **VBA-JSON v2.2.3** parser written by Tim Hall. (His github page seems to have been taken down at some point.) Here are the details for the problem:

- A simple (very small) parsing operation that usually takes 1 second will occasionally take 2-5 minutes to complete
- I tested with consistent information to be parsed, windows version, xcel version and VBA-JSON version, but random slow parse still happens
- I tracked the runtime, and when it does run slow, it will take increasingly longer amounts of time to run **json_ParseValue()** with each iteration through the do loop of **json_ParseObject.** The over all structure is recursive, so it makes sense that it would slow down over time with each dive, but normally this only takes one second, as every set of data is small enough that it shouldn't matter. (The three functions in use are listed below for reference)
- I heard of a bug that occured with an update in xcel where VBA-JSON parser would run very slow, but that bug would happen 100% of the time, where this one seems to pop in and out of existence.
- We have this running on ~30 computers at the same time, and this problem happens somewhat consistently for about half of them. But only the number of them is about the same, which computer has the issue is inconsistent.

To sum it all up, even though everything is consistent, this recursive series of functions will randomly run very very slow, but has nothing to do with the data fed to it.

Does anyone know why this would inconsistently happen? I feel like it would have something to do with pulling data from the server, but it only slows down inside the recursive function after having successfully pulled all data. Its just that sometimes that recursive slowing is drastically larger, even though the data is very small (8 values are parsed each time).

```
Private Function json_ParseObject(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Dictionary
    Dim json_Key As String
    Dim json_NextChar As String

    Set json_ParseObject = New Dictionary
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> "{" Then
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '{'")
    Else
        json_Index = json_Index + 1

        Do
            json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "}" Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                Exit Function
            ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "," Then
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
                json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
            End If

            json_Key = json_ParseKey(json_String, json_Index)
            json_NextChar = json_Peek(json_String, json_Index)
            If json_NextChar = "[" Or json_NextChar = "{" Then
                Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
            Else
                json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

```
Private Function json_ParseValue(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As Variant
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    Select Case VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
    Case "{"
        Set json_ParseValue = json_ParseObject(json_String, json_Index)
    Case "["
        Set json_ParseValue = json_ParseArray(json_String, json_Index)
    Case """", "'"
        json_ParseValue = json_ParseString(json_String, json_Index)
    Case Else
        If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 4) = "true" Then
            json_ParseValue = True
            json_Index = json_Index + 4
        ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 5) = "false" Then
            json_ParseValue = False
            json_Index = json_Index + 5
        ElseIf VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 4) = "null" Then
            json_ParseValue = Null
            json_Index = json_Index + 4
        ElseIf VBA.InStr("+-0123456789", VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)) Then
            json_ParseValue = json_ParseNumber(json_String, json_Index)
        Else
            Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', null, true, false, '{', or '['")
        End If
    End Select
End Function
```

```
Private Function json_ParseKey(json_String As String, ByRef json_Index As Long) As String
    ' Parse key with single or double quotes
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = """" Or VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) = "'" Then
        json_ParseKey = json_ParseString(json_String, json_Index)
    ElseIf JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys Then
        Dim json_Char As String
        Do While json_Index > 0 And json_Index <= Len(json_String)
            json_Char = VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1)
            If (json_Char <> " ") And (json_Char <> ":") Then
                json_ParseKey = json_ParseKey & json_Char
                json_Index = json_Index + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '""' or '''")
    End If

    ' Check for colon and skip if present or throw if not present
    json_SkipSpaces json_String, json_Index
    If VBA.Mid$(json_String, json_Index, 1) <> ":" Then
        Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting ':'")
    Else
        json_Index = json_Index + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: you mean this github? https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

Comment: I note that you have stated that  with the previously reported problem [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676288/excel-vba-running-extremely-slow-after-upgraded-to-office365-proplus?noredirect=1#comment101802796_57676288), [2](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/issues/145), you would expect to see this problem consistently. However, have you noticed this problem occurring with the latest VBA JSON release?

Comment: @QHarr, yes this looks like the right one! For some reason the link in version 2.2.3 readme file leads nowhere, but this looks like the right one! I will update it and do more testing. Thanks!

Comment: So far, everything is running perfectly. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Ok. Have left as answer in case others come across it. Please do let me know if error comes up again and I will delete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks related to the [VBA-JSON issue #145 reported on gitub](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/issues/145). The solution was to ensure to use the latest release [v2.3.0](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases/tag/v2.3.0)